# migrate SQL Server geography data to PostGIS geometry data

Tags: sql-server-2008, postgresql, ssis, spatial

I'm trying to use SSIS to transfer point data from a Geography column in SQL Server 2008 R2 to a geometry column in a Greenplum (Postgres 8.2.15) database with PostGIS.  I know there's a way to do the conversion outside of SSIS because I did it once a while back, unfortunately I don't remember what I did.

Comment: I think I'm on the right track.  I can use a query for the input that converts to POINT text using **geometry::STGeomFromWKB(myPointColumn.STAsBinary(), myPointColumn.STSrid).STAsText()**.  Then I won't need a data transformation at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  I used a query for the SQL Server source that converts to POINT text using:

> geometry::STGeomFromWKB(myPointColumn.STAsBinary(), myPointColumn.STSrid).STAsText()

That was all it took.  Now whether the point will be represented in PostGIS the way I intend it to I can't say at this point, but I'm hoping so.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html).
I'm not certain if you can do a direct import, but at the very least you can export to a SHP file, and then import the SHP file to PostGIS with [`shp2pgsql`](http://ostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide_20.bqg). It ships with PostGIS. b

Comment: Could you add a bit of explanation about how an SHP is imported to PostGIS?

Comment: Use the shp2pgsql tool. It ships with PostGIS. http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide_20.bqg